# Best practice for syncing databases on deploy

Tags: mysql, synchronization

In our projects we have three different instances of our typo3 websites (development, test, productive).
We are using MySQL as Database.

The development instance is on a different machine then test and productive.

If there are changes in the database we have to apply them by hand in all three instances. 
this is not a very safe approach and i wanted to ask you if you can give me an advice on how to sync those databases (or specific tables of it). The synchronisation has to be one way. So only from development to test, and from test to productive.

currenty we are deploying using an rsync script.

I found some solutions to sync the databases like mysql replication but i dont know if thats the best approach for my situation.
I want that the database sync starts automatically after the filesync finished.

I would be happy if someone could give me an adive on how to solve this problem the best way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a newbie with typo3 CMS and I need to deploy from DEV to PROD the changes made on the backend. So I think we have the same problem of sync between TYPO3 database.

Available solutions:
- Use external Typoscript files to avoid storing it in database and updating PROD with svn update
- Modify by hand the others parts

OR

- Using phpmyadmin new feature to synchronize databases

It's just theoritical solutions. At the moment, I can't test them.